# ListAdapter not inflating

Tags: android, android-adapter, listadapter

I'm working on showing list from arraylist of hashmap. I created my own adapter to show the list. But I'm not able to show it in list. I couldn't even debug inside that adapter. My code goes like this.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context _context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lists = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    public LayoutInflater myInflater;
    public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
        this._context = context;
        this.lists = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.myInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView==null)
        {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
            TextView TT = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.system_text);
            System.out.println("systemName name is"+this.lists.get(position).get("SystemName"));
            TT.setText(this.lists.get(position).get("SystemName"));
        }       
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: your getView implementation is also wrong. move this   `TT.setText(this.lists.get(position).get("SystemName"));` out of if

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the size of the **List** you want to show

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}
```

Check [this  for implementing the ListView with Custom BaseAdapter](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/#sthash.FMoBs8Kz.dpbs)

Check this [ViewHolder Pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `0` from the `getCount()` method, that means your `ListView` has no items. Please correct that to return the number of items you have in your list.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size(); // HERE
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
```

by

```
convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
```

Example:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return mInflater.inflate(view, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lists = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private final LayoutInflater myInflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        this.lists = list;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lists.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewWrapper viewWrapper = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.system_text);
            viewWrapper = new ViewWrapper();
            viewWrapper.textView = textView;
            convertView.setTag(viewWrapper);
        } else {
            viewWrapper = (ViewWrapper) convertView.getTag();
        }
        System.out.println("systemName name is"+ lists.get(position).get("SystemName"));
        viewWrapper.textView.setText(lists.get(position).get("SystemName"));
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewWrapper {
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```